# transition-delay not working on individual elements inside a container

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I am working on an intro animation for a website where the children slide up from the bottom (margin-top: 80px) with the container being set a fixed height and overflow:hidden to make it look slick.

The children have a transition-delay added to make them show up one after another but the whole line of elements are showing up together.

It would be great if someone could help me out with this code.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.anim_line').addClass('show');
}, 1400);
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #121212;
}


.anim_container {
  margin: 80px;
}

.anim_inner_container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: hsla(260, 91%, 84%, 1);
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(at 67% 61%, hsla(250, 67%, 53%, 1) 0px, transparent 40%),
    radial-gradient(at 34% -33%, hsla(249, 67%, 53%, 1) 0px, transparent 40%),
    radial-gradient(at 44% -15%, hsla(249, 67%, 53%, 1) 0px, transparent 40%);

  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;

  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

  font-family: 'Calibri';
  font-size: 64px;
  line-height: 96px;
}


.anim_line {
  height: 96px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
}

.anim_word {
  display: inline-block;

  margin-top: 100%;


  transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -o-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
}


.anim_word span {}

.anim_line.show .anim_word {
  margin-top: 0%;
}

.anim_line:nth-child(1) .anim_word:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: .15s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .15s;
}

.anim_line:nth-child(1) .anim_word:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: .25s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .25s;
}

.anim_line:nth-child(1) .anim_word:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: .35s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .35s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="anim_container">
    <div class="anim_inner_container">
      <div class="anim_line">
        <div class="anim_word">A</div>
        <div class="anim_word">product</div>
        <div class="anim_word">designer</div>
        <div class="anim_word">helping</div>
      </div>
      <div class="anim_line">
        <div class="anim_word">design</div>
        <div class="anim_word">beautiful,</div>
        <div class="anim_word"> user</div>
        <div class="anim_word">centered</div>
      </div>
      <div class="anim_line">
        <div class="anim_word">products</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use several different display properties for children but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Setting a margin-top for _one_ of those elements, moves the whole line down as one.

Comment: Taking a step back and removing all the animation, you can see that setting the margin of individual words affects the whole line: https://jsfiddle.net/93mLpe0u/

Comment: @freedomn-m There is indeed transition set on .anim_word class, I get that setting a margin-top for individual word affects the whole line but is there a workaround for this to work? I just need those words to show up with a delay in between. I tried to use translateY property earlier but that also didn't work.

Comment: @CBroe Is there a workaround for it? I tried to use translateY earlier but then the words don't show up at all. Please see this: https://jsfiddle.net/nitish2312/1oqrwxcj/

Comment: Your updated fiddle works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/u6eqzdf9/  looks like an issue with the letter colours making them hidden.  In the fiddle, I removed unnecessary css and added some borders (so it's easier to see what's happening) and tweaked the delays

Comment: FYI, [you don't need vendor prefixes for `transition-delay`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_transition-delay).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make 3 animations in row for every element with different delay, you need to defind animation for each element.
Edit: every word animation.
Edit 2: animation line words fix.
Edit 3: animation fix position.

example code:

```css
.container {
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        background: #121212;
      }

      .anim_container {
        margin: 80px;
      }

      .anim_inner_container {
        position: relative;
        background-color: hsla(260, 91%, 84%, 1);
        background-image: radial-gradient(at 67% 61%, hsla(250, 67%, 53%, 1) 0px, transparent 40%), radial-gradient(at 34% -33%, hsla(249, 67%, 53%, 1) 0px, transparent 40%),
          radial-gradient(at 44% -15%, hsla(249, 67%, 53%, 1) 0px, transparent 40%);

        background-clip: text;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        height: 300px;
        font-family: "Calibri";
        font-size: 64px;
        line-height: 96px;
        text-overflow: clip;
      }

      .anim_line {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: clip;
        height: 100px;
        margin-top: 0;

      }

      .anim_word {
        display: inline-flex;
        width: fit-content;
        height: 100px;
        margin-right: 20px;
      }

      .anim_line .anim_word div {
        overflow: hidden;
        animation-delay: calc(0.3s * var(--idx));
        -webkit-transition-delay: calc(0.3s * var(--idx));
        transition-delay: calc(0.3s * var(--idx));
        animation: show;
        animation-duration: calc(0.3s * var(--idx));
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
      }

      @keyframes show {
        from {
          margin-top: 500px;
        }
        to {
          margin-top: 0;
        }
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="anim_container">
        <div class="anim_inner_container">
          <div class="anim_line">
            <div class="anim_word"><div style="--idx: 0">A</div></div>
            <div class="anim_word"><div style="--idx: 1">product</div></div>
            <div class="anim_word"><div style="--idx: 2">designer</div></div>
            <div class="anim_word"><div style="--idx: 3">helping</div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="anim_line">
            <div class="anim_word"><div style="--idx: 4">design</div></div>
            <div class="anim_word"><div style="--idx: 5">beautiful,</div></div>
            <div class="anim_word"><div style="--idx: 6">user</div></div>
            <div class="anim_word"><div style="--idx: 7">centered</div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="anim_line">
            <div class="anim_word"><div style="--idx: 8">products</div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping :) I need the delay to be applied for each .anim_word element(each word in a line basically). Here also the whole line shows up together(instead of each word showing up after a certain delay). Need help in fixing that

Comment: Hope this edit in my snippet helps to animate each word

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to be working but there's a jerk in the animation towards the latter part of the animation, where they slide up as a line which is not ideal for production. Kindly help with that.

Comment: When they slide up is fixed now in snipped. Animation-duration is what you could adjust to your needs. Happy coding :)

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot! Got the hang of it now. One more query though: Is there a way to make the overflow:hidden work here? Because even though .anim_word has a height set to 100px(and overflow:hidden), the children are still visible when the animation starts.

Comment: Did you try to add z-index on anim_line class on all 3 elements?

Comment: Yeah did try that, but changing the position property on .anim_line makes everything disappear.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the exact result you are looking you can make sure of the css variables to calculate delay for each text element.

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #121212;
}

.anim_inner_container {
  position: relative;
  height: 384px;
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  font-size: 64px;
  line-height: 96px;
}

.anim_line {
  height: 96px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
}

.anim_word {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: hsla(260, 91%, 84%, 1);
  background-image: radial-gradient(at 67% 61%, hsla(250, 67%, 53%, 1) 0px, transparent 40%), radial-gradient(at 34% -33%, hsla(249, 67%, 53%, 1) 0px, transparent 40%), radial-gradient(at 44% -15%, hsla(249, 67%, 53%, 1) 0px, transparent 40%);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeInUp;
  animation-delay: calc(0.25s * var(--idx));
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 1.15s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99);
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(70px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="anim_container">
    <div class="anim_inner_container">
      <div class="anim_line">
        <div class="anim_word" style="--idx: 0;">A</div>
        <div class="anim_word" style="--idx: 1;">product</div>
        <div class="anim_word" style="--idx: 2;">designer</div>
        <div class="anim_word" style="--idx: 3;">helping</div>
      </div>
      <div class="anim_line">
        <div class="anim_word" style="--idx: 4;">design</div>
        <div class="anim_word" style="--idx: 5;">beautiful,</div>
        <div class="anim_word" style="--idx: 6;"> user</div>
        <div class="anim_word" style="--idx: 7;">centered</div>
      </div>
      <div class="anim_line">
        <div class="anim_word" style="--idx: 8;">products</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seem to be working alright. Thanks a lot for helping out :)

Comment: On second thought, I actually need the gradient applied to be working on the container instead of the .anim_word element. I see that you changed the gradient on individual .anim_word element instead which is not ideal for the animation. Kindly help me in making this work with the gradient applied on the container(.anim_inner_container)

Answer (score 0):

You have apparently 2 things here to take into account is that transition delay needs to be declared right after transition itself for it to work and in your animal container class ".anim_inner_container" you are using 96px for line-height so you need to put the height to minimum 384px

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.anim_line').addClass('show');
  }, 1400);
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #121212;
}


.anim_container {
  margin: 80px;
}

.anim_inner_container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: hsla(260, 91%, 84%, 1);
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(at 67% 61%, hsla(250, 67%, 53%, 1) 0px, transparent 40%),
    radial-gradient(at 34% -33%, hsla(249, 67%, 53%, 1) 0px, transparent 40%),
    radial-gradient(at 44% -15%, hsla(249, 67%, 53%, 1) 0px, transparent 40%);

  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  height: 384px;
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  font-size: 64px;
  line-height: 96px;
}


.anim_line {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
}

 .anim_word {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 100%;
}


.anim_line.show:nth-child(1) .anim_word:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0%;
  transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -o-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  transition-delay: .15s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .15s;
}

.anim_line.show:nth-child(1) .anim_word:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0%;
  transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -o-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  transition-delay: .25s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .25s;
}

.anim_line.show:nth-child(1) .anim_word:nth-child(3) {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0%;
  transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -o-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  transition-delay: .35s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .35s;
}

.anim_line.show:nth-child(1) .anim_word:nth-child(4) {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0%;
  transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  -o-transition: all 1.15s cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.05, 0.01, 0.99) 0s;
  transition-delay: .55s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .55s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="anim_container">
          <div class="anim_inner_container">
            <div class="anim_line">
              <div class="anim_word">A</div>
              <div class="anim_word">product</div>
              <div class="anim_word">designer</div>
              <div class="anim_word">helping</div>
            </div>
            <div class="anim_line">
              <div class="anim_word">design</div>
              <div class="anim_word">beautiful,</div>
              <div class="anim_word"> user</div>
              <div class="anim_word">centered</div>
            </div>
            <div class="anim_line">
              <div class="anim_word">products</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks again for taking a stab at it but I need it to work with the .anim_word as inline-block since I want all the words inside .anim_line to be in the same line. Using display:block changes that.